# FDISK human error

Tags: fdisk

I was trying to extend my root partition when I realised that I was not on my liveCD. But I already wrote the fdisk table. After rebooting, the filesystem is corrupted.

I tried to restore the fdisk with the old values which I took in picture with my phone. 
My problem is that my `/dev/sda1` didn't end on a cylinder boundary.

How to restore a fdisk table specifying blocks instead of cylinder to restore my filesystem ?

Do you need the fdisk pictures ?

Answer (score 0):

I found it on my own using `TestDisk`!

This tool is very usefull and the steps to use it are straight forward :

1. Download the last GParted live disk : http://gparted.org/livecd.php.
2. Boot on it (if you are using `vmware Player`, you can't do that, you have to switch to vmware workstation which adds a boot on BIOS where you can change VM boot options).
3. `GParted` live OS boots and let you launch a Terminal.
4. Run `testdisk` with command line and follow the very simple instructions (I just needed to run a quick search and hit enter to rewrite the fdisk table and reboot).